# Laravel 4: given this response, how can I access the "data" variable/key?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a unit test where a function does the following:

```
$response = Response::json('success');
```

`var_dump($response);` gives:

```
object(Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse)[184]
  protected 'jsonOptions' => int 0
  protected 'data' => string '"success"' (length=9)
  protected 'callback' => null
  protected 'encodingOptions' => int 15
  public 'headers' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag)[192]
      protected 'computedCacheControl' => 
        array (size=1)
          'no-cache' => boolean true
      protected 'cookies' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'headerNames' => 
        array (size=3)
          'cache-control' => string 'Cache-Control' (length=13)
          'date' => string 'Date' (length=4)
          'content-type' => string 'Content-Type' (length=12)
      protected 'headers' => 
        array (size=3)
          'cache-control' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'date' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'content-type' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      protected 'cacheControl' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  protected 'content' => string '"success"' (length=9)
  protected 'version' => string '1.0' (length=3)
  protected 'statusCode' => int 200
  protected 'statusText' => string 'OK' (length=2)
  protected 'charset' => null
```

it possible to access the `data` key?

```
protected 'data' => string '"success"' (length=9)
```

Because its protected, `$response->data` doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$response->getData();
```

---

Btw, in future you can answer such questions on your own by dumping all object methods:

```
dd(get_class_methods($response));
```

Comment: for sure, I wish I knew about `get_class_methods()` a long time ago! - will accept answer, checkbox widget wont let me accept till after 5-10 mins